# Qual é a diferença entre «símbolo» e «emblema»?

Tags: significado, diferenças

Estava a falar sobre futebol e disse:

> ...já para não falar do símbolo do Benfica<sup>1</sup>, que monocromático fica
>   feio.

E alguém me veio corrigir:

> Símbolo não, emblema. Os símbolos são Coluna, Eusébio, Bento,
>   Chalana,...

Pelo que pesquisei parece que são sinónimos, mas na priberam não faz nenhuma referência a isso.

Será um regionalismo? São sinónimos ou são diferentes?

---

<sub>1 - Imagem do Simbolo/Emblema do SLBenfica</sub>

[image]

Comment: símbolo é algo genêrico; emblema é um objeto o representação. Ou seja, um emblema é um tipo de símbolo. Um emblema é uma representação física ou identificador. https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emblema

Comment: @Lambie isso eu já tinha lido, mas, como sabes, a Wikipédia não é muito fidedigna.

Comment: Mas então a águia não é um símbolo do Benfica também? O Estádio da Luz? ... o emblema? :p Acho que era argumentável que o emblema é um símbolo. (Isto assumindo como verdadeira a premissa deles de que são coisas diferentes.)

Comment: Sim, mas acho que aqui sim. Por exemplo, o símbolo da paz é uma pomba branca, Se quiser ***colocar o símbolo na roupa***, se costura um emblema (o objeto físico feito de algum material ou tecido) dela na roupa. Um símbolo é uma representação, não um objeto físico. Certo?

Comment: Penso que um símbolo também pode ser um objeto físico, com a cruz católica, por exemplo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Símbolo" é um termo mais amplo - por exemplo, não apenas o emblema, mas também seu uniforme é um símbolo do clube.

"Emblema" é o símbolo oficial do time, sua insígnia, divisa, marca, [distintivo](http://www.aulete.com.br/distintivo), mas apenas um dos símbolos do clube, como fica claro em sua [página](https://www.slbenfica.pt/pt-pt/slb/historia/simbolos):

> O Emblema do Benfica é, sem dúvida alguma, a sua imagem de marca. Tal como a maior parte das tradições e símbolos do Clube, o emblema foi elaborado entre 13 de dezembro de 1903, quando surgiu a ideia de criar o Clube e a data da sua fundação, a 28 de fevereiro de 1904.

Nesse sentido, "símbolo" não é incorreto, mas "emblema" de fato pode ser preferível por ser mais específico.

Comment: Não fiquei totalmente convencido. ;)

Comment: @JorgeB.  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: stafusa, será que tens uma fonte que explique isso de forma mais clara?

Comment: @JorgeB. Uma fonte que explique que "símbolo" é mais geral que "emblema"? Você não tem a impressão que os dicionários já deixam isso claro?

Comment: eu estive a ver na priberam, mas não ficou claro para mim isso. Por isso é que fiz a pergunta.

Comment: @JorgeB. Talvez o [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br) deixe mais claro: *símbolo* - "Tudo o que, de maneira arbitrária ou convencional, representa uma outra coisa"; *emblema*: "Imagem ou sinal representativos de ideia, instituição, associação etc.". Para mim a primeira definição é claramente mais ampla que a segunda. Me parece, por exemplo, que um gesto pode ser muito mais facilmente chamado de símbolo que de emblema.